# sec:authorize не работает

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

у меня есть несколько пользователей с ролями USER и ADMIN. Хотел сделать блоки что видит только user или admin, вычитал что это можно реализоваться с помощью sec:authorize, но в конечном итоге блоки видят все. Так что я пологаю что sec сейчас не работает совсем. Как это можно исправить? Что добавить?

html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"
      lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
    <title>IndexFilm</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}">
</head>

<body>

<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    This content is only shown to authenticated users.
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">
    This content is only shown to administrators.
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('USER')">
    This content is only shown to users.
</div>

<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Зависимости:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.23</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменил заголовок html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"
      lang="en">
```

Добавил в конфигурации вот это:

```
   @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }
```

+hasRole заменил на hasAuthority

```
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">Админ контент</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('USER')">Юзер контент</div>
```

Теперь все работает. Надеюсь в будущем кому-то поможет